Can't override styles
I want to adapt tagify to the bootstrap 5 design, I tried to redefine the properties in CSS, but !important does not help, maybe there is a generally simple way that will allow you to easily make the design and behavior the same as other elements on the page.
@using CourseProject.Database
@using CourseProject.ViewModels
@using CourseProject.ViewModels.Template
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@model TemplateViewModel
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer
@inject AppDbContext _context

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.33.0/tagify.css">
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>@localizer["CreateTemplate"]</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="formTabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="general-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#general" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="general" aria-selected="true">@localizer["General"]</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="questions-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#questions" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="questions" aria-selected="false">@localizer["Questions"]</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="tab-content mt-4">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="general-tab">
                <div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Title" class="form-label">@localizer["Title"]</label>
                        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="form-label">@localizer["Description"]</label>
                        <textarea asp-for="Description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">@localizer["PreviewMarkdown"]</label>
                        <div id="markdownPreview" class="border rounded bg-light p-1"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="ImageFile" class="form-label">@localizer["UploadImage"]</label>
                        <div class="input-group custom-file-button">
                            <label asp-for="ImageFile" class="input-group-text" for="review-image" role="button">@localizer["ChooseFile"]</label>
                            <label for="review-image" class="form-control" id="review-image-label" role="button">@localizer["NoSelectedFile"]</label>
                            <input asp-for="ImageFile" type="file" class="d-none" id="review-image" accept="image/*">
                            <span asp-validation-for="ImageFile" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="TopicId" class="form-label">@localizer["Topic"]</label>
                        <select asp-for="TopicId" class="form-select">
                            <option value="">@localizer["SelectTopic"]</option>
                            @foreach (var topic in Model.Topics)
                            {
                                if (Model.TopicId == topic.Id)
                                {
                                    <option value="@topic.Id" selected>@topic.Name</option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option value="@topic.Id">@topic.Name</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="TopicId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Tags" class="form-label">@localizer["Tags"]</label>
                        <input asp-for="Tags" id="tags-input" class="form-control" placeholder="@localizer["Comma-SeparatedTags"]" />
                        <div id="tags-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tags" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="AccessType" class="form-label">@localizer["AccessType"]</label>
                        <select asp-for="AccessType" class="form-select">
                            <option value="Public">@localizer["Public"]</option>
                            <option value="Restricted">@localizer["Restricted"]</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="users-input" class="form-label">@localizer["AllowedUsers"]</label>
                        <input type="text" id="users-input" class="form-control" placeholder="@localizer["EnterUsernameOrEmail"]" />
                        <div id="users-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                            <label>@localizer["SelectedUsers"]</label>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sortButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    @localizer["SortBy"]
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sortButton">
                                    <li><button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="sortUsers('username')">@localizer["UserName"]</button></li>
                                    <li><button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="sortUsers('email')">@localizer["Email"]</button></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="selected-users"></div>
                    </div>

                    <input asp-for="AllowedUserNames" type="hidden" id="allowed-users" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="questions" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="questions-tab">
                <div>
                    <h4>@localizer["Questions"]</h4>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Questions" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <ul id="questions-container" class="list-group">

                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" id="add-question" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">@localizer["AddQuestion"]</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">@localizer["Save"]</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.33.0/tagify.js"></script>
<script>
    const questionsContainer = document.getElementById("questions-container");

    var draggedItem = null;

    document.getElementById("add-question").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const index = questionsContainer.children.length;
        const questionHTML = `
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center" data-index="${index}" draggable="true">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <input type="text" name="Questions[${index}].Title" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="@localizer["QuestionTitle"]" />
                            <input type="text" name="Questions[${index}].Description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="@localizer["QuestionDescription"]" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="Questions[${index}].Order" value="${index}" />
                            <select name="Questions[${index}].Type" class="form-select">
                                <option value="SingleLineText">@localizer["SingleLineText"]</option>
                                <option value="MultiLineText">@localizer["MultiLineText"]</option>
                                <option value="Checkbox">@localizer["Checkbox"]</option>
                                <option value="Integer">@localizer["Number"]</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[${index}].ShowInResults" class="form-check-input" value="true"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="Questions[${index}].ShowInResults" value="false"/>
                                <label class="form-check-label">@localizer["ShowInResults"]</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-2" onclick="this.parentElement.remove()">@localizer["Remove"]</button>
                    </li>`;
        questionsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", questionHTML);
    });

    questionsContainer.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select, button").forEach(element => {
        element.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
        element.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function canDrag(target, event) {
        const elementAtPoint = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

        return !elementAtPoint.closest("input, textarea, select, button");
    }

    questionsContainer.addEventListener("dragstart", function (e) {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains("list-group-item") || !canDrag(e.target, e)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        draggedItem = e.target;
        e.target.style.opacity = "0.5";
        e.target.classList.add("dragging");
    });

    questionsContainer.addEventListener("dragend", function (e) {
        e.target.style.opacity = "1";
        draggedItem = null;
        e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
        updateIndexes();
    });

    questionsContainer.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(questionsContainer, e.clientY);
        if (afterElement == null) {
            questionsContainer.appendChild(draggedItem);
        } else {
            questionsContainer.insertBefore(draggedItem, afterElement);
        }
        applyTransition(questionsContainer);
    });

    function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
        const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item:not(.dragging)")];

        return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
            const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
            const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
            if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
                return { offset: offset, element: child };
            } else {
                return closest;
            }
        }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element;
    }

    function updateIndexes() {
        [...questionsContainer.children].forEach((child, index) => {
            child.dataset.index = index;

            const inputs = child.querySelectorAll("input, select");
            inputs.forEach(input => {
                if (input.name.includes("Questions[")) {
                    input.name = input.name.replace(/Questions\[\d+\]/, `Questions[${index}]`);
                    if (input.name.includes(".Order")) {
                        input.value = index;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function applyTransition(container) {
        [...container.children].forEach((item) => {
            item.style.transition = "transform 0.2s ease";
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            [...container.children].forEach((item) => {
                item.style.transition = "";
            });
        }, 200);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const tagsInput = document.getElementById("tags-input");
        const usersInput = document.getElementById("users-input");
        const tagsDropdown = document.getElementById("tags-dropdown");
        const usersDropdown = document.getElementById("users-dropdown");

        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if (!tagsDropdown.contains(event.target) && event.target !== tagsInput) {
                tagsDropdown.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        function getCurrentInput(value) {
            const lastCommaIndex = value.lastIndexOf(',');
            return lastCommaIndex === -1 ? value : value.slice(lastCommaIndex + 1).trim(); 
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const usersInput = document.getElementById("users-input");
        const usersDropdown = document.getElementById("users-dropdown");
        const selectedUsersContainer = document.getElementById("selected-users");
        const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("allowed-users");

        var currentSort;

        var selectedUsers = [];

        function displayResults(results) {
            usersDropdown.innerHTML = '';
            if (results.length > 0) {
                results.forEach(user => {
                    const item = document.createElement('a');
                    item.classList.add('dropdown-item');
                    item.href = '#';
                    item.textContent = `${user.userName} (${user.email})`;
                    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        addUser(user);
                        usersDropdown.style.display = 'none';
                        usersInput.value = '';
                    });
                    usersDropdown.appendChild(item);
                });
                usersDropdown.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                usersDropdown.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        function addUser(user) {
            if (selectedUsers.some(x => x.userName === user.userName)) {
                return;
            }

            selectedUsers.push(user);
            sortUsers(currentSort);
            renderSelectedUsers();
        }

        function renderSelectedUsers() {
            selectedUsersContainer.innerHTML = '';
            selectedUsers.forEach(user => {
                const userDiv = document.createElement('div');
                userDiv.classList.add('d-flex', 'align-items-center', 'border', 'rounded', 'p-2', 'mb-2');
                userDiv.dataset.username = user.userName;

                const text = document.createElement('span');
                text.textContent = `${user.userName} (${user.email})`;
                text.classList.add('flex-grow-1');

                const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
                removeBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-danger', 'ms-2');
                removeBtn.type = 'button';
                removeBtn.textContent = "×";
                removeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    selectedUsers = selectedUsers.filter(x => x.userName !== user.userName);
                    renderSelectedUsers();
                    updateHiddenField();
                });

                userDiv.appendChild(text);
                userDiv.appendChild(removeBtn);
                selectedUsersContainer.appendChild(userDiv);
            });

            updateHiddenField();
        }

        window.sortUsers = function (criterion) {
            if (criterion === 'username') {
                selectedUsers.sort((a, b) => a.userName.localeCompare(b.userName));
            } else if (criterion === 'email') {
                selectedUsers.sort((a, b) => a.email.localeCompare(b.email));
            }
            currentSort = criterion;
            renderSelectedUsers();
        }

        function updateHiddenField() {
            hiddenInput.value = selectedUsers.map(x => x.userName).join(',');
        }

        usersInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
            const searchWord = usersInput.value.trim();
            if (searchWord.length > 1) {
                fetch(`/Template/GetUsers?begin=${searchWord}`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => displayResults(data))
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching users:', error));
            } else {
                usersDropdown.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if (!usersDropdown.contains(event.target) && event.target !== usersInput) {
                usersDropdown.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const markdownInput = document.getElementById("description");
        const markdownPreview = document.getElementById("markdownPreview");

        function renderMarkdown() {
            const markdownText = markdownInput.value;
            markdownPreview.innerHTML = marked.parse(markdownText);
        }

        markdownInput.addEventListener("input", renderMarkdown);

        renderMarkdown();
    });
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        $('#review-image').change(function(e) {
            var fileName = (e.target.files.length > 0) ? e.target.files[0].name : '@localizer["NoSelectedFile"]';
            $('#review-image-label').text(fileName);
        })

    });

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const tagsInput = document.getElementById("tags-input");
        const tagify = new Tagify(tagsInput, {
            delimiters: ",",
            whitelist: [],
            dropdown: {
                enabled: 0,
                position: "text",
                closeOnSelect: false
            }
        });


        const form = tagsInput.closest("form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function () {
            tagsInput.value = tagify.value.map(tag => tag.value).join(",");
        });

        tagify.on("input", function (event) {
            const searchWord = event.detail.value.trim();

            if (searchWord.length > 1) {
                fetch(`/Template/GetTags?begin=${searchWord}`)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((tags) => {
                        tagify.settings.whitelist = tags;
                        tagify.dropdown.show.call(tagify, searchWord);
                    });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #questions-container .list-group-item {
        transition: transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    }

    #questions-container .list-group-item.dragging {
        opacity: 0.7;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    #questions-container .list-group-item:not(.dragging) {
        transition: transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    }

    [data-bs-theme=dark] {
        --tagify-dd-color-primary: #198754 !important;
        --tagify-dd-bg-color: hsl(248, 40%, 25%) !important;
        --bs-primary-bg-subtle: #483d8b;
        --bs-primary-text-emphasis: #faebd7;
        --tag-text-color: var(--bs-body-color) !important;
    }
</style>



I tried something like that, but it's not worked, maybe because i am not a very familiar with CSS



First: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: Please edit to provide a [mcve]. Right now there's only (an image of) some CSS and nothing else.
